# Am I able to define what I want to sync via Marketing Cloud Connect?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, service-cloud-console

If I have multiple datasets in Salesforce, am I able to sync only subsets of this to Marketing Cloud via Marketing Cloud Connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can filter the synchronized records you choose to import using the Records Collection buttons.

When setting up a new Object in Synchronised Data Sources, you get options of filtering the synced records:

- To import all records, select **All records**.
- To import only records with an email address, select **All records with
  an email address**.
- To import only records created after a specified date, select **All
  records created since and specify the date**.
- To use a Boolean filter to import records, select **All records with**
  and enter the Boolean value. Select an attribute, set the operator,
  and choose True or False. (Observe, only conditions based on boolean fields are supported)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - if I choose 'All records with', am I able to use AND/OR operators to fine-tune the selection? Just trying to understand how I need to structure the data in order to omit a specific group from being part of the Marketing Cloud sync.

Comment: If you require more complex logic, I would set up appropriate measures in Core, summarised in a single "Sync with MC" boolean field, as the filter in Data Sources cannot operate on a combination of rules.

Comment: @LukasLunow Can it filter by Formula(Checkbox)? I created a field like that in Sales Cloud but it doesnt seem to show up on SFMC filter